# TYPO3 ver.: 8 How to properly customize felogin extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I would like to customize felogin (frontend lofin) extension template. I would like to copy the template file inside of my template extension folder, but I don´t know how to change the path with TypoScript, so Typo3 can look first into the template file which is located inside of my extension template folder.

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Answer (score 5):

The [configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/latest/Configuration/Index.html) is done like with every other extension:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
  templateFile = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin.html
}
```

Notice that felogin does not use Fluid, you might want to look at alternatives like [Hairu](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/hairu) if you need this.

Answer (score 5):

For TYPO3 ver.: `10.x` it could be set in `Setup` field of your TypoScript template as well.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.20 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.20 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.20 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer should be approved as the right one. The original documentation itself is outdated. Thanks @biesior

Comment: @AnuBhuvanendranNair actually at the time of asking (and answering by Mathias) accepted answer for TYPO3 ver. 8  _is/was_ valid, so it should stay like that. My answer is for TYPO3 10.