# Typo3: felogin in version 7?

Tags: typo3, felogin

I cannot find the key "felogin" when I click on "get extensions" in the backend. Why is that? The documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/) doesn't make any statements about version restrictions and according to videos I've found it should work with typo3 7 (I saw someone using "felogin" in typo3 7). But I cannot find it in the backend?

**EDIT**: Here's another example of someone using felogin even in typo3 8: [Typo3 8 How to properly customize felogin extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137879/typo3-8-how-to-properly-customize-felogin-extension)

Answer (score 1):

... felogin is part of the system and comes pre installed, hence it doesn't show up when I click on "get extensions" :D'