# Typo3 fe_login form doesn't showing on front-end

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

The default Login form not visible in Front-end of Official Server.

**I have Created an extension using Typo3 8.7.9 and Added an FE Login it was working perfectly in Local Setup in my System but when I installed this to the server and applied same settings. but login form is not visible.**

[image: Login Form of Form elements]

> The server is also Typo3 8.7.9

I'm using this form for FE Login the website users.
I have tried many settings but no hope.

Is there a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Did you get any error? enable error reporting from the typo3conf->localconfiguration.php and add `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` to setup ts

Comment: No, I didn't receive any error it is running perfectly. The area where I added form is blank. Remaining contents are shown below. I have added header text as "login" it is showing but not showing textbox or password field.

Comment: Here is helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137879/typo3-8-how-to-properly-customize-felogin-extension?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Sorry, I didn't create my own template. I just did as done in a local, just added the form instantly changes are visible in front.In the server is there any typoscript should be added?

Comment: Issue solved, somebody has put a typoscript path in server. I just removed it. now it is working. Thank you

Comment: Hi Karthik, today I have the same problem like you. What do you exactly mean with '..somebody has put a typoscript path in server..' ?!? My `felogin` worked correctly over years, yesterday I've made an PHP-Update from 5.5 to 7.0, now I still see the header but no login form ..  What happend?